# Loading an image from the server's file system dynamically in ASP.NET, via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**UPDATE:
This is now a dead question. While debugging further I realized the server (which I need to test this part of my code on, due to file permissions and such) was not getting my updates from VS2010, even though I published them to it. Frustrating. Anyway, all this works fine. Perhaps it could be used by someone else trying to figure out how to do a similar thing? Thanks everyone for your help.**

This one's been driving me crazy for a couple days.

What I have is a simple list of image thumbnails, which when clicked on should display the full-size image in another div via some jquery.

I get the thumbnail image data and full-size image's filepath from the database. The corresponding full-size image is stored on the same server as the IIS instance.

We do not want to display the filepath in the rendered HTML, so what we do is encrypt the filepath and send that as a parameter to a generic handler, which decrypts it, loads the file from the server, and outputs it as a byte array stream.

The handler works as intended, however the problem arises when trying to do the jquery html part. Instead of displaying the image in the div, it opens a new browser tab and shows the image from the handler just as would happen if javascript was disabled. What I need is the image to show in the #photosLarge div, which would happen if we used an image URL or something.

Here's my relevant code:

View:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    @For Each photo In Model.Photos
        Dim p As MyProject.Models.FolderImage = photo
        Dim FullSizeLink As String = "/Handlers/GetImage.ashx?file=" & p.DocPath
        @:<li><a href="@FullSizeLink" class="thumbnail"><img src="@p.Thumbnail.ToString" /></a></li>
    Next
</ul>

<div id="photoLarge"></div>
```

js:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
    var image = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#photoLarge').hide();
    $('#photoLarge').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#photoLarge').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
    return false;
});
```

My Handler:

```
Public Class GetImage
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim Common = New Common
        Dim FilePath As String
        Dim FileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo
        Dim FileStream As System.IO.FileStream
        Dim FileLengthInBytes As Long
        Dim QueryString As String
        Dim EncryptionKey as String = "df235s!2" 'that's not my real key ;-) 
        Try
            QueryString = context.Request.QueryString("file")
            FilePath = Common.DecryptString(QueryString.Replace(" ", "+"), EncryptionKey).Replace("+", " ")

            FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath)
            FileStream = FileInfo.OpenRead()
            FileLengthInBytes = FileStream.Length

            If (FileLengthInBytes > 0) Then
                Dim FileData(FileLengthInBytes - 1) As Byte
                FileStream.Read(FileData, 0, FileLengthInBytes)
                FileStream.Close()
                context.Response.Clear()
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(FileData, 0, FileData.Length)
                context.Response.End()
            End If
        Catch ex As IOException
            ReturnImageNotFound(context)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

''' etc '''
End Class
```

Comment: Any javascript error in sight when you look at the console of your javascript debugger? How about this: `$('#photoLarge').html($('<img/>', { src: image }));`?

Comment: None. Also, I should clarify (if it even matters) - the image shows up by itself in the same tab, not a new one.

Comment: If you put an alert just before returning false from your click handler, does it show?

Comment: It does not. I do know that javascript is being loaded on document load, because I have placed an alert in my "init" function that wraps that click handler, and that shows.

Comment: Is your `.click` handler executed at all? What do you mean by `init` function? You mean `document.ready`?

Comment: Please see my update. It was one of those frustrating circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the link isn't cancelling it's default action. You could try changing your function to this:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var image = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#photoLarge').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: I thought that would work too, alas, it doesn't. /frownieface.